# SPM with resources + TestFlight

Tags: swift, testflight, xcode12, swift-package-manager

I have an app that uses SPM. One of my packages contains resources (.xib files). While trying to upload the app to TestFlight I get an error which is a known issue, pointed here: https://developer.apple.com/news/releases/?id=06232020a as a last bullet:

> Apps that use Swift packages containing resources are not successfully imported. As a workaround, manually remove the CFBundleExecutable keys from the Info.plist files of the embedded resource bundles.

My question is how to use that workaround? My packages don't contain an Info.plist file.

Answer (score 0):

OK. It's working fine. What I did not understand was that I needed to change the Info.plist file that was located *inside* the archive. I initially thought it was supposed to be somewhere in the Package.

So the process is:

1. Create an archive and select it in Xcode Organizer.
2. Show in Finder.
3. Open package contents.
4. Go down the Folder structure (Products -> Application) until you find your .app file.
5. Again, show package contents.
6. There should be your package .bundle file. Again show package contents.
7. Here you should see the Info.plist file. Open it in Xcode and remove the "Executable file" entry.
8. Save and return to Xcode Organizer. Now you can Distribute the app.